# Search or filter in IRRE record

Tags: typo3, extbase

My TCA contains a column which is of type `inline`. The records, that can be added inline have different properties (e.g. a field called "active" which is of type `boolean`)

Is it possible to add a filter or search functionality to the inline field, which can filter out records (e.g. only show records where the property "active" is true)?

My solution until now: I added a new field to the TCA (and database), which shows the inline records makes use of the `foreign_match_fields` feature like shown below

```
'foreign_match_fields' => [
  'active' => '1',
],
```

But it somehow feels "bad" to have this new field in TCA just in order to show a subset of IRRE records.

Anyone know a better solution?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look into the documentation [WizardsConfiguration](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TCAReference/AdditionalFeatures/WizardsConfiguration/Index.html#examples). Its possible to use a searchCondition or you use a userFunc.